# mysql syntax error

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get values that equal both b.business_id = 22 and l.zip = 91326.  The easiest thing for me to try was `select l.*,b.name from buslocations AS l left join business as b where b.business_id = '22' and l.zip = '91326'` but apparently there is something wrong with that.  Any assistance with the correct syntax for two defined values would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to match the tables by some key or value using ON such as:

```
select l.*,b.name from buslocations AS l left join business as b ON l.x=b.Y WHERE  b.business_id = '22' and l.zip = '91326'
```

Comment: eek, I must be tired.  Thanks.

Comment: ...and dusoft wins the race.  : )

Answer (score 1):

Your join query needs to specify on which columns you're joining the two tables.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html